# undefined reference to; class public function not accessible at link time

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm trying to build a simple program where I defined a class and included it's header in Main. While linking, Linker complains about accessing any of the member function from class:

```
: undefined reference to voxel::anyFunction
```

even though functions are public and headers are included.

Originally I discovered the problem when creating an object of voxel - I had overloaded the default constructor, but I figure out the problem is present for any function from voxel class.

Here are some code excerpts:

#### voxel.hpp

```
class voxel
{
  public:
    //here defined some member variables
  //ommited the constructor
  void fillMemberValuesWithDummy();//sets all members to some dummy value
};
```

#### voxel.cpp

```
#include "voxel.hpp"
void voxel::fillMemberValuesWithDummy()
{
  //does the assignment to member variables
}
```

#### Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#include "voxel.hpp"
{
  voxel someVoxel;
  somevoxel.fillMemberValuesWithDummy();
}
```

I figure it is something very stupid I am (not) doing here, but can you tell me what?

Comment: which OS? Are you linking the voxel object file? Including header is not enough.

Comment: Are you linking `voxel.o` (or `voxel.obj`) with `main.o` (or `main.obj`) to create the executable?  If not, that's probably the trouble.

Comment: `int main()` function is missing in `Main.cpp`

Comment: So far I programmed in windows and seems like IDE took care of linking properly (I myself have little exp with it) will check some references. I forgot to paste the int main(), but it is definitely in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link all object files to get the executable. When you have just your two source files you can compile them directly:

```
g++ -o myprog.exe Main.cpp voxel.cpp
```

When you want to divide compile and link and do it this way:

```
g++ -c -o Main.o Main.cpp
g++ -c -o voxel.o voxel.cpp
g++ -o myprog.exe Main.o voxel.o
```

Feel free to create an appropriate Makefile that generates such commands.

Remove the `.exe` if you OS doesn't need it.

Comment: yes, this is the answer - I need to brush up on my compiling/linking. thank you !!